# The first bitcoin wallets?

Tags: wallet-recovery

I am trying to track down my old wallet, and I can't remember what kind of wallet it was! I am wondering what some of the first most popular wallets were, from the start of bitcoin in 2009 to about 2013! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, as far as I know, the most famous BTC wallet was and will always be Bitcoin Core Wallet

Then the rest of the most famous ones are as listed below:

- MultiBit (Now MultiBit HD)
- Electrum
- Blockchain.info
- Armory
- Bitcoin Knots

There are other wallets as well whose info you can get from the official site by [clicking here](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet)

Comment: Multibit, Electrum, blockchain.info appeared in 2011, Armory in 2012. Knots is much younger.

Answer (score 0):

1. If there no bitcoin in your wallet, you need not recovery your wallet. Just create another bitcoin account( private key/ public key).
2. If you remember your private key, you can recover your account by other wallets.